# Rails Stripe "Plan already exists"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm new to Rails and currently working on my first Website.
So here's my Problem:
Everytime I create a subscription for a service it gives me an Stripe::InvalidRequestError saying that the "Plan already exist". I figured out that is has to do something with the Stripe Plan ID.

What I want to do is, when the User clicks subscribe, it should check if the plan with the same id already exists. If the Plan with the same ID doesn't exist, it should create the Plan. If it does exist, it should not create the Plan and just subscribe the customer to the plan.

Here's what I tried:

```
  class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_order

    def create
    @user = current_user

    unless Stripe::Plan.id == @order.service.title
     plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
      :name => @order.service.title,
      :id => @order.service.title,
      :interval => "month",
      :currency => @order.amount.currency,
      :amount => @order.amount_pennies,
     )
   end
```

Above you can see that I thought that I could just use the ID of Stripe, but apparently this does not work.

```
   customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
     source: params[:stripeToken],
     email:  params[:stripeEmail],
   )

   # Storing the customer.id in the customer_id field of user
   @user.customer_id = customer.id

   Stripe::Subscription.create(
     :customer => @user.customer_id,
     :plan => @order.service.title,
   )

   @order.update(payment: plan.to_json, state: 'paid')
   redirect_to order_path(@order)

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_order_payment_path(@order)
    end

    private

    def set_order
      @order = Order.where(state: 'pending').find(params[:order_id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Inspect `Stripe::Plan.id` and print its value

Comment: It tells me !! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for Stripe::Plan:Class>. So it does not have a value when I try to print it. I assigned the ID to the String "test" when I first created it.

Comment: Can you post the params that are generated when the user clicks subscribe button?

Comment: Do you mean this? <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZJPFaGjSGLkACju0m7UkixWQ1kTXvko45HfLdfCP6wggmR8L7U6T7I56nrooYzCpqH7vg0VX7+pwG+WDqOiCmw==", "stripeToken"=>"tok_1Ab24XL51Wq7fLz4OQOZ8f44", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"123456@gmail.com", "controller"=>"payments", "action"=>"create", "order_id"=>"18"} permitted: false>

Comment: If the User clicks on the Subscribe Button the params are just <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"payments", "action"=>"new", "order_id"=>"18"} permitted: false>

Comment: So if he clicks on Subscribe, he gets to a new page which is the payment model. There I have `<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-name="<%= @order.service.title %>"
          data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"
          data-description="Service Description"
          data-amount="<%= @order.amount_pennies %>"
          data-currency="<%= @order.amount.currency %>">
        </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are checking for existence of a plan **isn't right**. `Stripe::Plan.id` doesn't work, so this `unless Stripe::Plan.id == @order.service.title` always fails. You should **get the plan** by using [*retrieve*](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_plan) method and use to like below

```
@plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(@order.service.title)
unless @plan
  plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
    :name => @order.service.title,
    :id => @order.service.title,
    :interval => "month",
    :currency => @order.amount.currency,
    :amount => @order.amount_pennies,
  )
end
```

> What I want to do is, when the User clicks subscribe, it should check
>   if the plan with the same id already exists. If the Plan with the same
>   ID doesn't exist, it should create the Plan. If it does exist, it
>   should not create the Plan and just subscribe the customer to the plan

Write the code to **create a subscription with that plan** in the `else` part of the above method. So the final method would be

```
@plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(@order.service.title)
unless @plan
  plan = Stripe::Plan.create(
    :name => @order.service.title,
    :id => @order.service.title,
    :interval => "month",
    :currency => @order.amount.currency,
    :amount => @order.amount_pennies,
  )
else
  subscription = Stripe::Subscription.create(
    :customer => Your customer here,
    :plan => @order.service.title
  )
end
```

Comment: Indeed, that's not "write" at all ;-)

Comment: @MickaelFM Haha nicely spotted :)